# Is bitmap index useful

Tags: database, indexing

In what kind of situations bitmap indices will be useful.

Comment: Eh, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap indexes are useful in a *read-mostly environment to support queries consisting of several filters that combined provides *high selectivity when each individual filter would have *low selectivity.

- *Read-mostly = Data is infrequently updated
- *High selectivity = returns few rows
- *Low selectivity = returns lot of rows

Comment: +1. I think the canonical examples are combined queries for multiple "enumerated" columns (e.g. gender='M' and position='manager', assuming there are few distinct positions).

Comment: +1, You phrased it better. Contrary to popular belief, the optimizer seldom picks bitmap indexeses on very low cardinality columns such as gender in practise anyway. The work effort required to reduce the resultset using an additional low cardinality column has to be compared to the effort required of just filtering the result using the bitmaps allready considered.